# cellForRowAtIndexPath animations triggered again on scroll/redraw

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Some of the labels in my cells have an animated appearance (code below).

However once there is more cells than room on the screen, upon scroll previously inserted cells get redrawn, and their animations triggered again.

How can I prevent this behavior ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"results"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"results"];
    }
   ...
    // Animations
    nameLabel.alpha = 0;
    nameLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-80, 0);
    priceLabel.alpha = 0;
    priceLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(+100, 0);
    cell.imageView.alpha = 0;
    cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-300, 0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        nameLabel.alpha = 1;
        nameLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
        priceLabel.alpha = 0.6;
        priceLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
        cell.imageView.alpha = 1;
        cell.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
    }completion:^(BOOL Finished){}];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could animate the cell in `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` that is called when the cell appears instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.